# why two strings that look identical are not same?

Tags: c#, .net, string, textbox, bunifu

I am a newbie in c# and coding. Please pardon me if I am asking a silly question. I first used `Directory.GetFiles()` as follows:

```
var savedfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\DiaryFiles");
```

Now, I have a textbox `bunifuTextbox1` in which I write some text "Amogh" which is a file name from "C:\DiaryFiles". Then I am using a function `nameRepair()` which is as follows:

```
private string nameRepair(string suspectfile)
{
    return  @"C:\DiaryFiles\" + suspectfile + ".akb";
}
```

(.akb is an extension). But, problem occurs when I try to do this:

```
foreach(string f in SavedFiles)
    if(f.Trim() == nameRepair(form.bunifuTextbox1.text).Trim())
    {
        //this code is not executed:(
    }
    else
    {
        //this part is executed
    }
```

Condition for `if` is always returning false

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:(I am posting whole code)

```
foreach (string f in savedfiles)
{
    this.label = new Label();
    this.label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(108, 36 + customLabels.Count * 26);
    this.label.Name = f;
    this.label.Text = (f.Replace(@"C:\DiaryFiles\","")).Replace(".akb", ""); 
    this.label.Width = f.Length * 20;
    this.label.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    if(f.Trim() == nameRepair(form.bunifuTextbox1.text.Trim()))
    {
        this.label.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        this.label.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }       
}
```

I tried to create labels at run time and want to change color of text on the labels which matches textbox text.

You can see the whole project here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q6eqiGvWnQYV7f_t8abG1cTwbVlUIqbm

Comment: You should share the contents of `f` and `form.bunifuTextbox1.Text`.

Comment: what is the value of f that you are comparing to?  Can you debug and look at the values?

Comment: Did you try putting a debug point right on your "if", check the values ?

Comment: Impossible to help you without exact sample data...

Comment: To start I would put the Trim on the TextBox.Text and not on the return value of the of _nameRepair_

Comment: Strings that are identical are also the same. If you think you have something that shows differently, the first step is to show us the contents of the two strings. You haven't even done that. I would recommend learning to use the debugger.

Comment: `var savedfiles` gets the file list, but `SavedFiles` is used as source in the `foreach` loop. Not clear. Use `Path.Combine()` to put together path pieces (Directory, FileName etc.).

Comment: Actually, there is a file named "Amogh" among other files at address C:\DiaryFiles in my pc which Directory.GetFiles saves in a string array savedFiles as C:\DiaryFiles\Amogh.akb. f is taking these addresses. So, why **if** part is not executed once in the foreach loop?

Comment: @amoghbhange you have not provided a [MCVE], you need to show us sample input.  Without that this question will likely be closed because we cannot reproduce your issue

Comment: Why not a simple if ( File.Exists( nameRepair( ... ) ) ) and remove the loop at all?

Comment: @amoghbhange these puzzling problems are really solved a lot faster if you just start using the debugger and look at what values are in your variables at the point of error. For us it is just a guess to spot the error because we don't have your inputs and we cannot see your whole code. For example what is that _form_ variable? Are you sure that is the correct instance of a form where the textbox has the text you want to search for? Please put a breakpoint on the if line (F9) and then hover with the mouse on the Text property to be sure you have the expected input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what's causing the problem.  But I *DO* know that it's a problem big enough to deserve an answer, because if it's not causing your problem *now*, it'll cause one for you in the *future*.

String comparisons are case sensitive.  Which means, in your line of code:

```
if(f.Trim() == nameRepair(form.bunifuTextbox1.text).Trim())
```

... you're checking to see if the strings are exactly the same, including a sensitivity to case.  Now, we know that your nameRepair function is explicitly adding a path:

```
return  @"C:\DiaryFiles\" + suspectfile + ".akb";
```

... all it takes is for your other file to have a name/path like:

```
c:\diaryfiles\********.akb
```

... and your comparison's not going to work.

Whenever I see a if (string == string) comparison, unless it's checking for a "" string, I view it as a bug-in-waiting.  Instead, you want something like:

```
if (stringA.Equals(stringB, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

... or similar.  Doesn't look as nice; doesn't hold a possible bug, though, either.